# trying to push files to github but git push -u origin main not working

Tags: git, github, openssh

```
Prabhakar@DESKTOP-EAUL6C1 MINGW64 /d/workstation/drum machine (main)
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/g-prabhakar/drum-machine.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/g-prabhakar/drum-machine.git (push)

Prabhakar@DESKTOP-EAUL6C1 MINGW64 /d/workstation/drum machine (main)
$ git push -u origin main
```

nothing is happening but after a while i cancel it using ctrl-c it asks for username for
'https://github.com'

and after i enter my username it shows error

```
Error: error writing "stdout": broker pipe

error writing "stdout": broken pipe
error writing "stdout": broken pipe
   while executing
"puts $::answer"
   (procedure "finish" line 14)
   invoked from within
"finish"
   invoked from within
".b.ok invoke"
   ("uplevel" body line 1)
   invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list $w invoke]"
   (procedure "tk::ButtonUp" line 24)
   invoked from within
"tk::ButtonUp .b.ok"
   (command bound to event)
```

p.s: i have already added sshkey to github

Comment: Have you tried setting the remote via SSH instead of HTTPS? That way it'll use your SSH key instead of asking for password.

Comment: Yes i did but it didnt work. So i uninstalled git and reinstalled it and in choose credential helper option i chose Git credential Manager and it worked